# Python SQLite3 / Nested cursor.execute

Tags: python, sqlite, nested, cursor, execute

Consider with this following piece of code:

```
for count in range(28, -1, -1):
    crsr.execute("SELECT board, win1, win2 FROM positions WHERE balls = ?", (count,))
    response = crsr.fetchall()
    print count, len(response)
    for possibility in response:
        internal = possibility[0]
        player = count & 1
        victor = 1 - player
        opponent = 2 - player
        victory = possibility[opponent]
        if victory:
            crsr.execute("UPDATE positions SET result = ? WHERE board = ?", (victor, internal))
        else:
            subsequent = derive((internal, count))
            for derived in subsequent:
                external = reduce(derived[0])
                crsr.execute("SELECT result FROM positions WHERE board = ?", (external,))
                colour = crsr.fetchall()
                if colour[0][0] == player:
                    victor = player
                    break
            crsr.execute("UPDATE positions SET result = ? WHERE board = ?", (victor, internal))
```

Consider with the line:

`response = crsr.fetchall()`

Whenever that there are as much as 10<sup>7</sup> rows in `response`, the above statement returns a memory error, even on a system with 8 GB of RAM.

So, I decided that I would change with the following piece of code:

```
for count in range(28, -1, -1):
    crsr.execute("SELECT board, win1, win2 FROM positions WHERE balls = ?", (count,))
    response = crsr.fetchall()
    print count, len(response)
    for possibility in response:
        internal = possibility[0]
```

to:

```
for count in range(28, -1, -1):
    crsr.execute("SELECT COUNT(board) FROM positions WHERE balls = ?", (count,))
    sum = crsr.fetchall()
    total = sum[0][0]
    print count, total
    crsr.execute("SELECT board, win1, win2 FROM positions WHERE balls = ?", (count,))
    for possibility in range(total):
        response = crsr.fetchone()
        internal = response[0]
```

Now that the line:

`response = crsr.fetchone()`

makes use of the `crsr` variable for performing with SQLite3 selection query for every iteration of `possibility` in `range(total)`.

There are already other `crsr` statements in the same 'for' loop:

`crsr.execute("UPDATE positions SET result = ? WHERE board = ?", (victor, internal))`

with that statement occurring twice, and

`crsr.execute("SELECT result FROM positions WHERE board = ?", (external,))`.

with that statement occurring once.

So, whenever the `crsr` variable from the line: `response = crsr.fetchall()` changes with every iteration of `possibility` in `range(total)`, will it not conflict with the other `crsr` statements already in the same 'for' loop?

We cannot create with other cursor variables for executing with different SQLite3 queries, because crsr is defined by using `crsr = connection.cursor()` for a specific database file, as soon as it is initialized (whichever is `spline.db`, in this particular case).

So, I would like to know that if there are any other alternative solutions available for it whichever are efficient enough quite directly.

Comment: Your explanation why you can't create multiple cursors does not make sense. Why can't you call `connection.cursor()` multiple times?

Comment: Thank you for your response. So if I quite directly call `crsr1 = connection.cursor()` and `crsr2 = connection.cursor()` and if I am executing `crsr1.execute(query1)` and `crsr2.execute(query2)` inside of the same 'for' loop itself, then will `crsr1` and `crsr2` not quite directly both conflict with each other, of themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A result set is part of the cursor object, so whenever you call `execute()`, any previous query on the same cursor object is aborted. The only way to avoid this is to use `fetchall()` to read all result rows before the next query is executed.

To be able to execute multiple simultaneous queries, you must use multiple cursors. Simply call `connection.cursor()` multiple times.

---

Please note that you must not modify a table that you are still reading from (even if you are using multiple cursors); changed rows might be skipped or read twice by the read cursor. If you cannot use `fetchall()`, put the results of the first query into a temporary table:

```
crsr1.execute("CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_pos(board, win1, win2)")

for count in ...:
    crsr1.execute("INSERT INTO temp_pos SELECT board, win1, win2 ...")

    crsr1.execute("SELECT board, win1, win2 FROM temp_pos")
    for row in crsr1:
        if ...:
            crsr2.execute("UPDATE positions ...")
        else:
            crsr2.execute("SELECT ... FROM positions ...")
            ...
    crsr1.execute("DELETE FROM temp_pos")

crsr1.execute("DROP TABLE temp_pos")
```